# MongoDB - Multiple $or operations

Tags: key, mongodb

How would I have multiple $or operations? So far I've tried the following but it silently ignores the 2nd $or.

```
{
  $or: [{a: 2}, {a: 3}], 
  $or: [{b: 5}, {b: 4}]
}
```

I assume this is because I'm using two identical keys. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Mongo 2.0 added an $and operator, so you can do a query like this:

```
db.things.find({$and: [{$or : [{'a':1},{'b':2}]},{$or : [{'a':2},{'b':3}]}] })
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and

Comment: Thanks! Mongo docs explain about that here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Object can not have two properties with the same name (You have two `$or` in your case), and this will happen also with every query that does not respect this rule (only one property will be taken in consideration).

```
// try this Javascript code (this will throw an errors some programming languages)
const x = { a: 1, a : 2 };
console.log("x:", x);
// this will output x: {a: 2} // <= the "a: 1" was gone.
```

This should ([Nader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141272)) should fix your problem, You can also convert your query into one `$or` with all possible values, but it can get messy with more values/variables (Not recommended, but it can get rid of the two properties with same name issue).

```
// this will not work (your question) 
{
  $or: [{a: 2}, {a: 3}], 
  $or: [{b: 5}, {b: 4}]
}
// this will work (I recommend using $and in your use-case)
{
 $or: [
  {a: 2, b: 4}, 
  {a: 2, b: 5},
  {a: 3, b: 4}, 
  {a: 3, b: 5},
 ] 
}
// this is a better solution for your problem (Nader).
{
  $and: [
  { $or: [{a: 2}, {a: 3}] }, 
  { $or: [{b: 5}, {b: 4}] }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For multiple like in sql we use $in and for not we use $nin 
vc is our collection name here.We are finding those string contains cpu or memo.

```
db.collection('vc').find({   "name" :   { $in: [ /cpu/, /memo/ ]   }     }
```

Answer (score -6):

$and will not do the job, since the 2nd $or will not validate if the first one fails.

From the Mongo man page:

*The $and operator uses short-circuit evaluation. If the first expression (e.g. ) evaluates to false, MongoDB will not evaluate the remaining expressions.*

Nested $or however should do the trick:

db.things.find({$or: [{$or : [{'a':1},{'b':2}]},{$or : [{'a':2},{'b':3}]}] })