# Mongodb multiple OR condition on same key

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDb I've got documents into my collection as such:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("561f925017e74f6a08012c65"),
  'timestamp' => new MongoDate(1444877100, 0),
  'value' => 0,
)
```

Of course all documents with their own timestamp.

How can I find the documents with multiple OR-conditions on the timestamp?
For example find all records that have a timestamp between 1444877100 and 1444877105 OR timestamp between 1444877120 and 1444877150.

For example, in Mysql it'd be:

```
WHERE (
  (timestamp >= 144877100 AND timestamp <= 1444877105) OR
  (timestamp >= 1444877120 AND timestamp <= 1444877150)
)
```

I can't seem to get it right or find any help in the right direction. I have checked this question as well ([MongoDB - Multiple $or operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150061/mongodb-multiple-or-operations)) but that uses set values and I can't figure out how to do it with $gte and $lte (at least I think that's the way to go).

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the query in MongoDB shell or via a driver? - Which language are you trying to solve this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator which perform a logical **OR** operation of two or more expressions. Of cause the [`$gte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte) and [`$lte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte)  respectively selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than or equal to (i.e. >=) a specified value and  less than or equal to (i.e. <=) the specified value.

```
$result = $collection->find(['$or' => [ 
    ['timestamp' => ['$gte' => new MongoDate(1444877100), '$lte' => new MongoDate(1444877105)]], 
    ['timestamp' => ['$gte' => new MongoDate(1444877120), '$lte' => new MongoDate(1444877150)]]
]]);
```

Since the [`find()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) returns a cursor you will need to loop through each element using the foreach loop. Something like this:

```
foreach ( $result as $doc ) { /* dosomething(); */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`{ $or: [ { timestamp: { $lte: someValue, $gte: someValue2 } },  { timestamp: { $lte: someValue3, $gte: someValue4 } } ] }`